# wenzhixin Bootstrap table - getVisibleColumns

Tags: bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap-table plugin - http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn

There is a method for accessing hidden columns - getHiddenColumns but there is no getVisibleColumns method. Actually I want to search on the visible columns only for this I need the visible column names.

How can I get it? 
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have searched in the library and found there is a method - getVisibleFields. But it is not accessible. I think it should be allowed to make access.

Comment: im pretty sure this came up in github issues for bootstrapTable, if that was you or you find it there please link from here (posting as self answer if core issue for you is solved, or as edit in OP if not)

Comment: Added the getVisibleColumns method in the plugin. Therefore, we can use that now.

Comment: if solved, put a self answer and accept it so this SO post marked solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the getVisibleColumns method in the plugin. Therefore, we can use that now. So, it is solved now.